# Waypoints not rendered - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, axios

I am trying to get the waypoints from an AXIOS call and use the response to feed the `city` into a `waypts` array. When I try to add the waypoints to the route, the map will only display the route from start to end. The console shows no waypoints in the request. If I add the waypoints manually, they will appear. When I print `waypts` to the console, it is formatted correctly for the `waypoints` field in the route. The `filterselect` in the `initMap()` function is a dropdown in the vue component's template that contains all the route ids.

**overview.js**

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(context, directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var origin, dest;
  var waypts = [];
  var stops;
  for (var i=0; i<context.routes.length; i++) {
    //console.log(route)
    if(context.routes[i].id == context.filter){
      origin = context.routes[i].start;
      dest = context.routes[i].dest;
      stops = Promise.resolve(getAllStops(context.routes[i].id));
      stops.then(function(value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
          if(!(value[i].city === dest)){
          waypts.push({
                    location: value[i].city.toString(),
                    stopover: true
                  });
              }
        }
        })
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(waypts)
  directionsService.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: dest,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      console.log(response)
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

async function getAllStops(routeid){
  var stops=[];
  var thisResponse =[];
  try{
    let response = await AXIOS.get('/api/route/getStops/' + routeid + '/', {}, {});
    thisResponse = response.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < thisResponse.length; i++) {
    stops.push(response.data[i]);
    }
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error.message);
  }
  return stops;
}
//...
methods: {
      initMap: function(){
        this.$nextTick(function(){
          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
          var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 45.49, lng: -73.61},
            zoom: 9
          });
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          var thisContext = this;
          var onChangeHandler = function() {
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(thisContext, directionsService, directionsDisplay);
          };
          document.getElementById('filterselect').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        })
      }
}
```

**Console log (waypts, then response) for route 83**
[image: console_log]

**AXIOS Response for `routeid` 83**

```
[{"locationId":84,"city":"Johannesburg","street":"28th","user":{"ratings":[4.5,4.8,4.1,2.8],"username":"elle12","password":"****","firstName":"Elle","lastName":"Woods","phoneNumber":"**********","city":"Cape Town","address":"*** Trinidad","avgRating":4.05,"numTrips":4,"role":"passenger","car":null,"status":"Active","request":null},"route":{"routeId":83,"seatsAvailable":1,"startLocation":"Cape Town","date":"2018-12-04T15:00:00.000+0000","car":{"vehicleId":81,"brand":"Tesla","model":"X","licensePlate":"123456","driver":{"ratings":[4.0],"username":"nono12","password":"****","firstName":"Noam","lastName":"Suissa","phoneNumber":"**********","city":"Montreal","address":"345 road","avgRating":4.0,"numTrips":1,"role":"driver","car":null,"status":"Active","request":null},"route":null},"status":"Scheduled","stops":null},"price":13.0},
{"locationId":85,"city":"Hoedspruit","street":"Kruger","user":{"ratings":[2.8],"username":"george12","password":"****","firstName":"George","lastName":"Lasry","phoneNumber":"**********","city":"Johannesburg","address":"*** Hamt","avgRating":2.8,"numTrips":1,"role":"passenger","car":null,"status":"Inactive","request":null},"route":{"routeId":83,"seatsAvailable":1,"startLocation":"Cape Town","date":"2018-12-04T15:00:00.000+0000","car":{"vehicleId":81,"brand":"Tesla","model":"X","licensePlate":"123456","driver":{"ratings":[4.0],"username":"nono12","password":"****","firstName":"Noam","lastName":"Suissa","phoneNumber":"**********","city":"Montreal","address":"345 road","avgRating":4.0,"numTrips":1,"role":"driver","car":null,"status":"Active","request":null},"route":null},"status":"Scheduled","stops":null},"price":11.0}]
```

Comment: What does your javascript console say? How many waypoints are you adding? As it is, your question is off-topic as the issue can not be reproduced with the given code. Please read on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MrUpsidown The code cannot be verified as I would have to include thousands of lines of code and files. I believe that the issue is caused by the implementation in the `for` loop within `calculateAndDisplayRoute()`  and how `waypts` is misinterpreted by `waypoints:`. I will include the console log

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  That won't require thousands of lines of code.

Comment: @geocodezip There is not much more I can add. Please try your best to understand and identify the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip the issue is caused by the function skipping the promise and not waiting for it to finish. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`directionsService.route()` is executed before the Promise is returned. Therefore, the `waypts` array is not populated in time.

Solution:

```
stops.then(function(value) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: dest,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      console.log(response)
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
});
```

Minimal. Complete. Verifiable.